# Cannot installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, msys

I'm installing Rails on Windows. When I run `gem install rails` I received message

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200417-11800-rf5t47.rb 
extconf.rb

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/nio4r- 
2.5.2/gem_make.out
```

I have no idea about that error. How to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but might be still be relevant for people arriving through search. I installed the latest Ruby + devkit from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/, and it worked (Windows 10)